# Ubuntu 16.04 bonding config not working

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, bonding, static-ip, ubuntu-16.04

I have a weird problem with my bonding setup.
Yesterday I've tried to install Pi Hole on my Ubuntu 16.04 server and it messed up my bonding.  I've uninstalled Pi Hole, but it's not working anymore.

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp9s0
iface enp9s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp10s0
iface enp10s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 10.10.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.10.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
bond-slaves enp7s0 enp8s0 enp9s0 enp10s0
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
```

My /etc/modules:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

loop
lp
rtc
bonding
```

Now, when I boot the interfaces getting these IP's:

enp7s0: 169.254.15.22

enp8s0: **10.10.1.32**

enp9s0: 169.254.15.22

enp10s0: 169.254.15.22

So enp8s0 getting a DHCP address and I can't figure out why.

If I do ifup bond0, it's showing that bond0 is already configured.

Could anyone tell why the bond won't work.

Thanks

Comment: None of the interfaces should get IPs. Just some things to look at: Check logs and dmesg, manually run ifup and/or other scripts with debugging (bash -x, strace, etc...). Uninstall isc-dhcp-client? You don't need it right? Manually assemble bond and see what happens. `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`. Post anything interesting in your question.

Comment: 169.254.15.22 ip address means that interface want to get ip via dhcp but didn't get it and after timeout set autoconfig IP. Maybe something was reconfigure all interfaces. See syslog file.

Comment: Looks like a pretty classic case of having network manager running. Make doubly sure it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite my answer, because i wasn't see at first time that you used PiHole. I'm sorry.

I watched PiHole installer and understood that all static and dynamic ip configs are in dhcpcd5. Remove it and reboot your server.

```
sudo dpkg -r dhcpcd5
```

Comment: ifenslave is installed, and not using NetworkManager, since its the server version of Ubuntu.